# Get the data from mysql in xml format in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp

I am trying to get data from mysql and set the all data in xml format but I am unable to do this task. My code is:

```
abc.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
try
{
Connection connection=DBCreation.getConnection();
Stirng query="select latitude,longitude,time from jam_info";
Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

%></body>
</html>
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
<markers>
   <marker>
      <latitude></latitude>
      <longitude></longitude>
      <time>100</time>
   </marker>
</markers>
```

I think this is wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: where are you reading from resultset ?

Comment: i confused where i need to read resultset,but anyway  i want to set the all data items to the markers tag using loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this getXXX method will depend upon the type of the column holding the value.

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%

        Connection connection=DBCreation.getConnection();
        Stirng query="select latitude,longitude,time from jam_info";
        Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        out.println("<markers>");
        while(rs.next()) { 

               out.println("<marker>");
               out.println("<latitude>" + rs.getXXX("latitude") + "</latitude>");
               out.println("<longitude>" + rs.getXXX("longitude") + "</longitude>");
               out.println("<time>" + rs.getXXX("time") + "</time>");
               out.println("</marker>");
           }
        out.println("</markers>");
 %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanku sanjeev,it is xml type data so we have to set content type in xml format,how this works

Comment: try changing `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

Comment: thanku for ur reply sanjeev, server throws exception because it wont allow try block(java) code here because we are setting text/xml right.i think this is not correct way will u please execute code do some changes.i am struggled from past 2 days will u please help me

Comment: if u find any requirement like this in net,please let me know and thanks alot for all ur repleys

Comment: did you try putting <%@ page contentType="text/xml" %> as well

Comment: thanku very much friend, u can develop simply for this i am struggle since morning,i cant express more than this once again thanku